# Proof on diagonalizability.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I can't attack this problem, i just don't know where to begin.

> Let $A \in M_n( \mathbb{C})$ , $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, such that $A=xy^*$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $y^*x \neq 0$

I can see that $y^*x$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, because:

$Ax=(xy^*)x=x(y^*x)=(y^*x)x$

since $y^*x \in \mathbb{C}$

But then i just can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you show that $A$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

Of course we have to assume $x,y \neq 0$. If one of those is zero, $A$ is zero and clearly diagonalizable.

Given $x,y \neq 0$, $A$ is rank $1$-matrix. It is very easy to characterize diagonalizability of a rank $1$ matrix. It is diagonalizable if and only if it has a non-zero eigenvalue. So you have already figured it out, since you have figured out that $y^*x$ is a eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $y \in \mathbb{C}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and define the linear functional $\ell(v)=y^\ast v$. Suppose $\ell(x) \neq 0$ for some unit length vector $x$, i.e. $x= y/||y||$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{C}^n = \operatorname{span}[x]\oplus\ker\ell \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \operatorname{span}[x] \perp \ker\ell.
\end{align}
Let us find an orthonormal basis for $\ker \ell$, say $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$, which means $\{x, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then it follows
\begin{align}
M= [ x, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}]
\end{align} 
is an invertible matrix (actually, an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $M^{-1}=M^T$). Moreover, we have that
\begin{align}
M^T xy^\ast M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
v_1\\
\vdots\\
v_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} xy^\ast [x, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x^\ast y &  0 & \ldots &  0\\
0 & 0 &  \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \ldots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \ldots & \ldots  & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Hence $xy^\ast$ is diagonalizable if $x^\ast y \neq 0$.

For the converse, it follows that $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to a non-zero eigenvalue of $xy^\ast$ if and only if $v \parallel x$. But we have $x^\ast y=0$. Hence $xy^\ast$ is a rank 1 matrix with all zero eigenvalues (basically a Jordan block), which contradicts the fact that $xy^\ast$ is diagonalizable.